# Impact of lenient true

Tags: java, date-format

The [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javatext/DateFormat.html#setLenient%28boolean%29) of `DateFormat` states that with lenient `true`

> the parser may use heuristics to interpret inputs that do not preci$sely match this object's format...

My question is how to know the impact of `lenient=true` on common date manipulation classes like, for instance, `SimpleDateFormat`?

More precisely I would to know if those heuristics can change their behavior over time with the same date input. For instance, if a date xyz can be parsed/guessed one way in 2019 and differently in 2020.

I have a web app running since about 10 years and in the last days I received a few `0022-mm-dd` dates. Looks like `22-01-01`, for instance, is interpreted as `0022-01-01`. Nothing in the base code seems to have changed so I'm wondering if the heuristic parser is now working differently.

Comment: Why would you need to know this? If it’s not in the documentation it’s an implementation detail. Anecdotally I think it’s unlikely you’ll see the change your expecting - it’s more around days out of range etc.

Comment: @jakg I have a webapp running since about 10 years and in the last days I received a few `0022-mm-dd` dates. Looks like `22-01-01`, for instance, is interpreted as `0022-01-01`.  Nothing in the base code seems to have changed so I'm wondering if the heuristic parser is now working differently.

Comment: I'm assuming you've updated the JRE in the past 10 years? That's probably much more likely to be where the variation is coming from.

Comment: Lenient or not, parsing behavior is unlikely to change unless the timezone rules change for the timezone used by your SimpleDateFormat.

Comment: If and when you can, upgrade your code to [java.time, the modern Java date and time API.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html) `DateFormat` and its concrete subclass `SimpleDateFormat` were always troublesome, and poor and insufficient documentation is a minor one of their problems. That said, I am convinced that using pattern `yyyy-MM-dd` `SImpleDateFormat` has always parsed `22-01-01` into 0022-01-01 (never 1922-01-01 nor 2022-01-01). May it be that the input you are getting has changed?

Comment: A third possible explanation is that you are using one of `DateFormat`’s localized formats, and that the localized format has changed in a recent Java version. Which is your Java version and which is your locale or the locale you are using for parsing? Also please show us your code -- not the full code, but a [mre].

Comment: Leniency in this case is not about format as the docs would have us believe, but about interpreting out-of-range values so that when there are 30 days in November, November 31 is interpreted as December 1. Theoretically they could change the interpretation in a new Java version, but like the others I seriously doubt that this has happened or ever will. Also becuase `DateFormat` and `SimpleDateFormat` are long outdated, so there would really be no good reason to put any effort into their maintenance with the risk of breaking old code, which is the only place where they are reasonably used.

Comment: @OleV.V. Well, for that I'd compare the source code; it's available after all. They could have made it a stub to the new API, although I seriously doubt that.